# How to resample from 8K to 16K with librosa or torchaudio as ffmpeg do it?

Tags: ffmpeg, scipy, librosa, openai-whisper, torchaudio

In my app,

- I'm getting array of audio sample (with sample rate =**8000**) which was loaded with `torchaudio.load`
- I need to use this audio array and run whisper (STT).
- I want to avoid from loading the wav file again with whisper ([load_audio](https://github.com/openai/whisper/blob/main/whisper/audio.py))  (for efficiency) and to resample the array to **16000**.
- `whisper.load_audio` use `ffmpeg` to load and resample the audio to **16000**.
  I'm trying to use `librosa` or `torchaudio` and resample the audio array but It always seems that the resample methods are not the same.
- (I assume that if I use other resample method not as the whisper model was trained on, I can get bad results).

Example:
loading test.wav file (with SR=**8000**) and print the 5 first cells:
`whisper_audio = whisper.load_audio(file)` => `[-0.00082397 -0.00115967 -0.00186157 -0.00231934 -0.00222778, ...]`

loading with `torchaudio` and resample it with `librosa`:
`librosa.resample(vad_audio, orig_sr=8000, target_sr=16000, scale=True, res_type='kaiser_best')`
=>  `[-0.00082317 -0.0010577  -0.0013937  -0.0016688  -0.00186235`

seems different values.

How can I resample the audio in the exact way `ffmpeg` do it ?

Comment: 1) I experimented with the librosa resampling method you mention, and it seems to match ffmpeg quite well. In terms of correlation, it gets an correlation of 95% on my test signal. I think librosa would likely work fine. 2) I experimented with trying to get PyAV, which is a ffmpeg wrapper, to resample audio. Unfortunately, it seems to use `abuffer` and `aformat`, rather than SWR, which is the default method under ffmpeg. Couldn't get it to use SWR. You might find the FFMPEG resampling docs helpful. https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-resampler.html

Comment: Have you tried pyaudio?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `torchaudio.io.StreamReader` to load and resample audio. This functionality is implemented with `ffmpeg`, so you might be able to produce the same waveform.

When you use the `add_basic_audio_stream` method with `sample_rate` option, it will use FFmpeg's filter function to apply resampling.

https://pytorch.org/audio/2.1.1/generated/torchaudio.io.StreamReader.html#add-basic-audio-stream

If the `ffmpeg` command is using non-default re-sampling method, you need to construct the same filter description and pass it to `add_audio_stream` method.

https://pytorch.org/audio/2.1.1/generated/torchaudio.io.StreamReader.html#add-audio-stream